# SQL command to display a grouped-by column and other column with specific value

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have the following table:

```
+---------+------+------------+
|Player   |Game  |Status      |
+---------+------+------------+
|Player01 |GameA |uncompleted |
|Player02 |GameA |uncompleted |
|Player03 |GameC |completed   |
|Player04 |GameA |uncompleted |
|Player05 |GameB |completed   |
|Player06 |GameB |completed   |
|Player07 |GameA |uncompleted |
|Player08 |GameA |completed   |
|Player09 |GameC |uncompleted |
|Player10 |GameB |completed   |
|Player11 |GameB |uncompleted |
|Player12 |GameA |completed   |
.....
+---------+------+------------+
```

and want to display number of players and number of players completed the game for each game:

```
+------+-----------------+----------+
|Game  |Number of Players|Completed |
+------+-----------------+----------+
|GameA | 6               | 2        |
|GameB | 4               | 3        |
|GameC | 2               | 1        |
...
+------+-----------------+----------+
```

What is the simplest SQL select command to perform that task?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select Game , count(*) NumPlayers,
sum(case when status = 'completed' then 1 else 0 end) completed 
from table
group by game
```

Comment: You guys are so fast. I was about to answer my first question and two of you beat me to it...

Answer (score 0):

You want a conditional summmation:

```
select game, count(distinct Player) as NumPlayers,
       sum(case when status = completed then 1 else 0 end) as Status
from t
group by game
```